# How to remove first element from a TreeMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I need to implement a container which contains maximum 32 values where elements are sorted by key. In C++ it's kinda easy, cause every map is sorted by it's key, in Java I'm not that sure.

So I read some and came with a TreeMap.

How to efficently remove the oldest element from a TreeMap (the first one)?

Thanks!

Comment: *"oldest"* !== *"first one"*? What exactly do you want to put in, in what kind of order and what element do you want to remove?

Comment: `map.iterator().next().remove()` or `map.remove(map.firstKey())`. If by "oldest" you mean access or insertion order, you probably want `LinkedHashMap`, not `TreeMap`

Comment: The TreeMap isn't sorted by the order you've put them in. It sorts them by the key-value. So you can't really delete the oldest one, if it isn't the one which is in the first position in your Treemap aftersorting.

Comment: The key here is a 'sequenceNumber' which is being incremented in the same loop.
map.push(sequenceNumber++, myobject); Something like that

Answer (score 2):

You said

> The key here is a 'sequenceNumber' which is being incremented in the same loop.

By TreeMap [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) it states

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

So you can easily remove the first element after sorted.

Example:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

map.put(1, "ac");
map.put(2, "ef");
map.put(3, "bd");

map.remove(map.firstKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which has method [removeEldestEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)).

Comment: But I would need to sort it, cause it is not sorted always, right?

Comment: Yes, but since 32 is a small value, sorting should be fast enough. Do it each time you need sorted representation.

Comment: RemoveEldestEntry does not change the Map in any way, it just returns false and does nothing. The Map must be overidden. Check the javadoc (Sample use) how to do it.